# How to execute set of commands after sudo using python script

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

I am trying to automate deployment process using the python. In deployment I do "dzdo su - sysid" first and then perform the deployment process. But I am not able to handle this part in python. I have done similar thing in shell where I used following piece of code,

```
/bin/bash

psh su - sysid  << EOF

. /users/home/sysid/.bashrc

./deployment.sh

EOF
```

this handles execution of deployment.sh very well. It does the sudo and then execute the script with sysid id.
I am trying to do similar thing using python but I am not able to find any alternative to << EOF in python.

I am using subprocess.Popen to execute dzdo part, it does the dzdo, but when I try to execute next command for e.g. say "ls -l", then this command will not get executed with the sysid, instead, i had to exit from sysid session and as soon as i exit, it will execute "ls -l" in my home directory which is of no use. Can someone please help me on this?

And one more thing, in this case I am not calling any deployment.sh but I will call commands like cp, rm, mkdir etc.

Answer (score 1):

The text between `<< EOF` and `EOF` in your shell script example will be written to the standard input of the `psh` process.  So you have to redirect the standard input of your `Popen` instance and write the data either directly into the `stdin` file of your instance or use the `communicate()` method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

SHELL_COMMANDS = r'''\
. /users/home/sysid/.bashrc
./deployment.sh
'''


def main():
    process = Popen(['psh', 'su', '-', 'sysid'], stdin=PIPE)
    process.communicate(SHELL_COMMANDS)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you need the output of the process' stdandard output and/or error then you need to pipe those too and work with the return value of the `communicate()` call.

Comment: Thank you so much BlackJack. The solution you provided is worked. Just tell me one more thing, how to use shell variables in shell commands. For e.g. SHELL_COMMANDS=r'''\ . /users/home/$USER/deployment.py ''' In this, you can see I am trying to pass $USER, a shell variable in path. But of course python is not able to expand this variable. Could you please tell me if i can use shell variable here?

Comment: As it is executed by a shell that shouldn't be a problem at all.